# Flutter how to show FPS (frame per second) to the user?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to show FPS aka Frame per second to the user in Flutter? Is there any widget or package for that?

**Note:**

I am not asking for FPS during testing.

Comment: Here is good demo : https://medium.com/@matanlurey/building-a-reactive-fps-counter-in-dart-5f7c0177289e

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how to build FRP (functional-reactive program[s]) in Dart
[image]

````dart
    import 'dart:async';

/// Returns a [Stream] that fires every [animationFrame].
///
/// May provide a function that returns a future completing in the next
/// available frame. For example in a browser environment this may be delegated
/// to `window.animationFrame`:
///
/// ```
/// eachFrame(animationFrame: () => window.animationFrame)
/// ```
Stream<num> eachFrame({Future<num> animationFrame(): nextFrame});
````

Determining frames-per-second means I want to check, at sporadic moments in my application, how long it’s been since I last was able to check. Assume the following:
Rendering is normally measured in seconds, or how many frames fit
1000 milliseconds (ms) is one second
Time it takes to render a frame is the difference between two timestamps
We can start with emitting a timestamp every “frame”

> In Dart, which is single-threaded and based on an event loop, we’ll assume that if we can get control of the event loop at least once every  (idle time) that all previous work was effectively the frame.

I tried implementing it rather naively — I created a new StreamController, and used Future.delayed (which delegates to a Timer on all platforms) to inform when the next frame is:

````
    import 'dart:async';

/// A cross-platform implementation for requesting the next animation frame.
///
/// Returns a [Future<num>] that completes as close as it can to the next
/// frame, given that it will attempt to be called 60 times per second (60 FPS)
/// by default - customize by setting the [target].
Future<num> nextFrame([num target = 60]) {
  final current = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  final call = math.max(0, (1000 ~/ target) - (current - _previous));
  return new Future.delayed(
    new Duration(milliseconds: call),
    () => _previous = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch,
  );
}

/// Returns a [Stream] that fires every [animationFrame].
///
/// May provide a function that returns a future completing in the next
/// available frame. For example in a browser environment this may be delegated
/// to `window.animationFrame`:
///
/// ```
/// eachFrame(animationFrame: () => window.animationFrame)
/// ```
Stream<num> eachFrame({Future<num> animationFrame(): nextFrame}) {
  StreamController<num> controller;
  var cancelled = false;
  void onNext(num timestamp) {
    if (cancelled) return;
    controller.add(timestamp);
    animationFrame().then(onNext);
  }
  controller = new StreamController<num>(
    sync: true,
    onListen: () {
      animationFrame().then(onNext);
    },
    onCancel: () {
      cancelled = true;
    },
  );
  return controller.stream;
}
````

```
import 'package:fps/fps.dart';

/// Prints 10 timestamps, each printed ~every 13.33ms.
void main() {
  eachFrame().take(10).listen(print);
}
```

> Note: This is not always accurate — on web specifically we can do this much better with window.animationFrame, but again, I wanted something that would run cross-platform out of the box.

OK, so instead of adding the timestamp, I need to calculate and output the frames per second. I could have done this inline, but instead to make it yet-more-extensible I’ve implemented it via a simple StreamTransformer, which is code I can use on-top of any Stream via transform:

````
/// Computes frames-per-second given a [Stream<num>] of timestamps.
///
/// The resulting [Stream] is capped at reporting a maximum of 60 FPS.
///
/// ```
/// // Listens to FPS for 10 frames, and reports at FPS, printing to console.
/// eachFrame()
///   .take(10)
///   .transform(const ComputeFps())
///   .listen(print);
/// ```
class ComputeFps implements StreamTransformer<num, num> {
  final num _filterStrength;

  /// Create a transformer.
  ///
  /// Optionally specify a `filterStrength`, or how little to reflect temporary
  /// variations in FPS. A value of `1` will only keep the last value.
  const ComputeFps([this._filterStrength = 20]);

  @override
  Stream<num> bind(Stream<num> stream) {
    StreamController<num> controller;
    StreamSubscription<num> subscription;
    num frameTime = 0;
    num lastLoop;
    controller = new StreamController<num>(
      sync: true,
      onListen: () {
        subscription = stream.listen((thisLoop) {
          if (lastLoop != null) {
            var thisFrameTime = thisLoop - lastLoop;
            frameTime += (thisFrameTime - frameTime) / _filterStrength;
            controller.add(math.min(1000 / frameTime, 60));
          }
          lastLoop = thisLoop;
        });
      },
      onCancel: () => subscription.cancel(),
    );
    return controller.stream;
  }
}
````

```
import 'package:fps/fps.dart';

void main() {
  eachFrame()
    .take(10)
    .transform(const ComputeFps())
    .listen(print);
}
```

I now get output something like this:

> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60
> 60

Looks good! I’ve [included the source code and an example repo on github.](https://github.com/matanlurey/fps)

[original](https://medium.com/@matanlurey/building-a-reactive-fps-counter-in-dart-5f7c0177289e)

Comment: This is just full copy of Matan Lurey's article and repository. So sentences like "I decided to try building an FPS counter" are simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

I don't know if there's a package which can help you constantly show FPS to the user, but if you want to do it manually, you can try this approach:

```dart
class _FpsPageState extends State<FpsPage> {
  bool _shouldCount = false;
  var _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_shouldCount) _count++;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _shouldCount = true;
            _count = 0;
            Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1),(timer) {
              setState(() {
                if (timer.tick >= 1000) {
                  timer.cancel();
                  _shouldCount = false;
                }
              });
            });
          },
          child: Text(_count != 0 ? 'FPS: $_count' : 'START'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```