# Flutter - Continuously call a function as long as a button is pressed

Tags: flutter, function, dart, button

I was wondering if it exists a way to continuously call a function on Flutter as long as a button (any kind of button is okay) is pressed.

For example:

```
GestureDetector(
 child: Container(),
 onLongPressStart: () {}, // Start of the function
 onLongPressEnd: () {}, // End of the function
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

1. on long tap, start the timer and call the function
2. on long press end, stop the timer

Example:

```html
Timer? timer;

GestureDetector(
          onLongPressStart: (detail) {
            setState(() {
              timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 250), (t) {
                print(Random().nextInt(1000) + 9);
              });
            });
          },
          onLongPressEnd: (detail) {
            if (timer != null) {
              timer!.cancel();
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            child: const Text("press me"),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            color: kRedColor,
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Timer` for this case.

```dart
  //how often method will be called
  Duration delay = const Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  Timer? timer;

  void continuousWork() {
    debugPrint("I am working c ${timer!.tick}");
  }

  void onJobEnd() {
    debugPrint("Job END");
    timer?.cancel();
    timer = null;
  }

  void onJobStart() {
    if (timer != null) return;
    debugPrint("Job started");
    timer = Timer.periodic(delay, (timer) {
      continuousWork();
    });
  }
```

And use case will be using `GestureDetector`

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {},
  onTapDown: (details) {
    onJobStart();
  },
  onTapUp: (v) {
    onJobEnd();
  },
  child: Text("tap"),
),
```

More about [`dart-async`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-async/dart-async-library.html), and another way of doing this using CancelableOperation from [async package](https://pub.dev/packages/async)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code and preview of what you are asking:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67465570/1456151

---

[image]

```dart
class _FpsPageState extends State<FpsPage> {
  bool _shouldCount = false;
  var _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_shouldCount) _count++;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _shouldCount = true;
            _count = 0;
            Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1),(timer) {
              setState(() {
                if (timer.tick >= 1000) {
                  timer.cancel();
                  _shouldCount = false;
                }
              });
            });
          },
          child: Text(_count != 0 ? 'FPS: $_count' : 'START'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```